# Laravel Adding request to url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to create a link that leads to `www.website.com/account/payments?status=verified`

Here's the code

```
<a href="{{ url('account/payments', ['status' => 'verified']) }}">Verified</a>
```

However the above is leading me to `www.website.com/account/payments/verified`

Is there any way to achieve what i want without using the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a discrepancy between `url()` and `route()` in regards to the second (array) argument. Using the latter your function call will work as expected when `status` isn't defined as a route parameter; it'll tack it on to the path as a query string.

```
// in routes file
Route::get('account/payments', 'Controller@method')->name('account.payments');


route('account.payments', ['status' => 'verified']);
// www.website.com/account/payments?status=verified
```

The `url()` function however simply appends all elements of the second argument onto the supplied *path* instead of a *query string*. Still, it's possible to define an inline query string:

```
url('account/payments?status=verified')
// www.website.com/account/payments?status=verified
```

Here's another example to see how `url()` handles the second argument. It merely inserts the "extra" path segments:

```
url('account/payments?status=verified', ['bar'])
// www.website.com/account/payments/bar?status=verified
```